# Junit5 is unable to execute shell commands within tests

Tags: java, junit, junit4, junit5

I had question about running scripts using Junit 5. I have the following piece of code:

```java
public class RunMvnSubprocess {
    @Test
    public void main() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        String[] cmd = new String[]{"mvn.cmd", "-version"}; // command to be executed on command prompt.
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
        try (BufferedReader output = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()))) {
            String line;
            while ((line = output.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }
        }
        p.waitFor();
    }
}
```

I get *no output* when I run it using Junit 5.7.0. However, running this on Junit 4.13.2 works fine.

Please note that I am running this piece of test in Windows 10 Pro version 21H1.

EDIT:

Modifying

```java
new String[]{"mvn.cmd", "-version"}
```

to

```java
new String[]{"cmd", "/c", "\"mvn -version\""}
```

works for me, but launching a subshell is a bad practice so I am keeping this workaround as a last resort.

Answer (score 1):

Note that you are implicity running a sub-shell as the Windows command `CMD.EXE` is called to interpret the contents of `mvn.cmd`, so your value of `cmd` is equivalent to:

```
cmd = new String[]{ "cmd", "/c", "call mvn.cmd -version"};
```

If you get no error code from `waitFor` or no output or no exception, then the issue will be reported in the STDERR stream. Change to use ProcessBuilder instead and you can merge STDERR to STDOUT as follows:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(cmd);
// No STDERR => merge to STDOUT
pb.redirectErrorStream(true);

Process p = pb.start();
```

Also, no need to write much code to consume STDOUT:

```
try(var stdo = p.getInputStream()) {
    stdo.transferTo(System.out);
}

int rc = p.waitFor();
if (rc != 0) throw new RuntimeException("test failed");
```

Hopefully this will explain your problem with the mvn command.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, @DuncG. I am still not getting any output, but the value of rc is 1 so I get a RuntimeException raised.

Comment: So my sub process is exiting with a non-zero code (the test suite exits with 0), and I don't know why because there is no message.

Comment: You've switched to ProcessBuilder as above? You should clarify what "mvn.cmd" contains as your command that works lists `{"cmd", "/c", "\"mvn -version\""}`: that means your fix could be running either MVN.EXE or MVN.CMD depending on the contents of the current directory, and the environment vars `Path` and `PATHEXT`  so isn't the same as the first `cmd`.

Comment: yes, I switched to process builder like above and tried using `mvn.exe` and `mvn.cmd`. Using the former throws an IOException while subprocess corresponding to  `{"mvn.cmd", "-version"}`' exits with code 1. I even tried to call `read` on the input stream and it returns -1 which means there are no bytes in the stream.